# Need to display desaturated MKMapView tiles

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, uiimage, mkmapview

I am looking to display an MKMapView that sports desaturated map tiles so that I can add overlays that won't visually compete with the MapView.

I explored many ideas and didn't come up with a solution.

One way to address the issue is to access to original tiles so that I could redraw as overlay after desaturation process.

Any idea?

Comment: Any idea of what? Also, what are the many ideas you explored? We don't want to waste time telling you what you already know.